# How to join() - chapter 8 Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python

From Automate The Boring Stuff With Python book:
"Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB appears in the text file. For example, a text file may look like this:

The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.

The program would find these occurrences and prompt the user to replace them."

I'm almost done, but I can't seem to figure out how to .join the last list on the file. I've looked online and tried the methods. Instead of getting a string out of join, I get the whitespace in ' '.join(mod4) separating the letters within each list string value. 
[ ' A n ' ,   ' o n e ' ,   ' t w o ' ,   ' a n d ' ,   ' t h r e e ' ,   ' f o u r ' ]
Everything else does the job.

```
#! python3

import re

madText = open('madText.txt', 'w')

text = 'An ADJECTIVE, a NOUN, an ADVERB and a VERB.'

madText.write(text)
madText.close()

content = re.split('\W+', text)

for i in content:

    if i == "ADJECTIVE":
        replaceRegex = re.compile(r'(ADJECTIVE)')
        print('Enter an ADJECTIVE:')
        ADJECTIVE = input()
        output = replaceRegex.sub(ADJECTIVE, str(content))

    elif i == "NOUN":
        replaceRegex = re.compile(r'(NOUN)')
        print('Enter a NOUN:')
        NOUN = input()
        output = replaceRegex.sub(NOUN, str(output))

    elif i == "ADVERB":
        replaceRegex = re.compile(r'(ADVERB)')
        print('Enter an ADVERB:')
        ADVERB =  input()
        output = replaceRegex.sub(ADVERB, str(output))

    elif i == "VERB":
        replaceRegex = re.compile(r'(VERB)')
        print('Enter a VERB:')
        VERB = input()
        output = replaceRegex.sub(VERB, str(output))

content = re.split('\W+', output)
#content = list(output.split(' '))
content = ' '.join(content)
print(content)
madLibs = open('madText2.txt', 'w')
madLibs.write(content)
madLibs.close()
```

Comment: What did you expect? What happened instead? `mod4` is a string, were you expecting a list of words?

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks like `.sub()` from the `re` module isn't returning what you think ti's returning. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: have you actually tried printing out `str(content)`? using `re.sub` on the string representation **of a list** is rarely what people mean to do.

Comment: `'This is what I was expecting'` and `[ ' N o t ', ' t h i s ' ]` Yes I tried printing it several ways. I'll check the docs, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a basic assumption that is preventing you from completing this.  Your assignment of `mod4` is based on previous assignments and their order.

Instead what you should be doing is initializing an `output` variable to `[]` and appending the words to it as you loop through `content`.  You would add your adlib words along with the real words.

Once you have built your output list, *then* you use `join` to turn that `output` into a string.

Also, using `regex` is overkill.  Let's assume you've made an `output = []` before the loop.

```
if i == 'NOUN':
   print('Enter a NOUN:')
   noun = input()  # raw_input() on Python 2
   output += noun
[...]
```

Now as you hit each adlib token you replace it with the inputted text and build your output list.

Comment: To be honest I had figured out earlier something like that would be the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for the same exercise.

```
import os, re

def start():
    fileName = input('Enter the file name: ')
    exist_fileName = os.path.abspath(fileName)
    if os.path.exists(exist_fileName) == True:

        text_file = open(exist_fileName)
        text_content = text_file.read()
        text_file.close()
        print(text_content)


        text_regex = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB|ADVERB')
        match_text = text_regex.findall(text_content)

        for match in match_text:
            user_input = input('Enter ' + match + ': ')
            text_content = text_content.replace(match, user_input, 1)
        print(text_content)

        new_fileName = 'new_' + fileName
        new_file = open(new_fileName, 'w')
        new_file.write(text_content)
        new_file.close()

    else:
        print('The file you have entered does not exist. Please enter a valid file name.')
        start()

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I made. I guess I deserved getting -2 downvotes within 4 minutes of posting the above. :)

```
import re

madText = open('madText.txt', 'w')
text = 'An ADJECTIVE, a NOUN, a VERB and an ADVERB and a NOUN.'
madText.write(text)
madText.close()
content = re.split('(\W+)', text)

for i in content:
    if i == 'NOUN':
        content.insert(content.index('NOUN'), input('Replace ' + i + ': '))
        content.remove('NOUN')
    elif i == 'VERB':
        content.insert(content.index('VERB'), input('Replace ' + i + ': '))
        content.remove('VERB')
    elif i == 'ADVERB':
        content.insert(content.index('ADVERB'), input('Replace ' + i + ': '))
        content.remove('ADVERB')
    elif i == 'ADJECTIVE':
        content.insert(content.index('ADJECTIVE'), input('Replace ' + i + ': '))
        content.remove('ADJECTIVE')

content = ''.join(content)
print(content)
madLibs = open('madText2.txt', 'w')
madLibs.write(content)
madLibs.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for this same problem, thanks to Alex Antony above for a little help.

```
import re

madlib_text = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.'

madlib_file = open('madlib.txt', 'w')
madlib_file.write(madlib_text)

madlib_regex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{2,}')
mo = madlib_regex.findall(madlib_text)

for x in mo:
    if x == 'ADJECTIVE':
        prompt = input('Enter an adjective: ')
    else:
        prompt = input(f'Enter a {x.lower()}: ')
    madlib_text = madlib_text.replace(x, prompt, 1)

print('\n' + madlib_text)

user_madlibs = open('completed_madlibs.txt', 'w')
user_madlibs.write(madlib_text)

user_madlibs.close()
madlib_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach as those above. Comments should be fairly descriptive:

```
#! python3
# madLibs.py - Prompts user for a text file.
#   At each occurence of ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, and VERB, user is prompted for a word.
#   The user's word of choice replaces the placeholder.
#   The file is overwritten with the user's word choices in the same structure.

# Import modules.
import re
from pathlib import Path

# Prompt user for file input.
file = input('Please input a file (path).\n')

# Store the file's contents as a string variable.
filecontent = open(file).read()

# Breaks the string into a list with each word, punctuation mark, or space conserved at an index.
listRegex = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]|[\s]", filecontent)

# Scan through the list and look for placeholder words.
#   At each instance, prompt the user for a replacement and make the substitution.
for character in range(len(listRegex)):
    if listRegex[character] == 'ADJECTIVE':
        adjective = input('Enter an adjective.\n')
        listRegex[character] = adjective
    elif listRegex[character] == 'NOUN':
        noun = input('Enter a noun.\n')
        listRegex[character] = noun
    elif listRegex[character] == 'ADVERB':
        adverb = input('Enter an adverb.\n')
        listRegex[character] = adverb
    elif listRegex[character] == 'VERB':
        verb = input('Enter a verb.\n')
        listRegex[character] = verb

# Convert the new list into a new string.
string = ''
for character in listRegex:
    string += character
print(string)

# Overwrite the original file.
Path(file).write_text(string)
```